# Error: "java: cannot find symbol - symbol: method inRange"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, java-deployment-toolkit

I am working on a Java project that utilizes OpenCV 4.1.2 for image processing. However, I'm encountering an error when using the Imgproc class. The specific error message I'm receiving is:
`java: cannot find symbol symbol:   method inRange(org.opencv.core.Mat,org.opencv.core.Scalar,org.opencv.core.Scalar,org.opencv.core.Mat) location: class org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc` 
I have successfully imported the necessary classes and have verified that I'm using OpenCV 4.1.2 with Java 8. The other methods of the Imgproc class, such as cvtColor and GaussianBlur, work fine. However, the inRange method seems to be unrecognized.my code:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.highgui.HighGui;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Press Alt+Entrée with your caret at the highlighted text to see how
        // IntelliJ IDEA suggests fixing it.

        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread("C:\\Users\\hp probook x360 435\\Videos\\pfa\\111.jfif");
        Mat BLUR = new Mat();
        Mat DST=new Mat();
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(image, BLUR, new Size(5,5), 0);
        Scalar LOWER=new Scalar(18,90,180);
        Scalar UPPER=new Scalar(35,255,255);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(image, BLUR, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
        Imgproc.inRange(BLUR,LOWER,UPPER,DST);
        HighGui.imshow("Original Image", image);
        HighGui.imshow("Grayscale Image", BLUR);
        HighGui.waitKey(0);

        // Press Maj+F10 or click the green arrow button in the gutter to run the code.

    }
}
```

I have checked my build configuration, verified the correct imports, and ensured that the OpenCV library is properly set up.

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue and successfully use the inRange method? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe `Core::inRange`?

Comment: [There is no such method](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/javadoc/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html). Why are you expecting there to be?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the method "inRange" is in this class "org.opencv.core.Core"

```
//so this line  
Imgproc.inRange(BLUR,LOWER,UPPER,DST) 
should be changed to 
Core.inRange(BLUR,LOWER,UPPER,DST);
```